# Django specify default address and default port when run server

Tags: python, django

Is there a way i can specify the IP:Port in DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE (setting.py), instead of using

```
python manage.py runserver <ip>:<port>?
```

like we specify ALLOWED_HOST, INTERNAL_IPS etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add `default address` and `default port` in your `settings.py`:

```
from django.core.management.commands.runserver import Command as runserver

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
runserver.default_port = '8000'        # <-- Your port
runserver.default_addr = '127.0.0.1'   # <-- Your address
```

Then just need run `python manage.py runserver`